# What is the equivalent to SQL's SELECT count(*) for Redis?

Tags: redis

I have a Redis Hash set up something like

```
 "Profile:123": 
   "updatedAt": "2021/04/19"
```

and I need to be able to retrieve the count of all the Profiles that were updated on a given date. The SQL query would look something like `SELECY count(*) FROM profiles WHERE updatedAt = "2021/04/19";` but I've been given the user story to implement that on a Redis cache and I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Given what you've told us, it's not (except by iterating over the whole hash), but it's hard to say without seeing the whole DB design. Ask someone at work, not us.

Comment: @hobbs Asking StackOverflow is my last ditch effort after documentation, consulting my team (all of whom are as new to Redis as I am), and general Googling. Thanks for your genius tip, though!

Comment: Redis isn't the kind of database you're used to. It's not arbitarily "queryable". Every data type has its own particular interfaces, and to support a given access pattern you need to store data in a structure that fits that pattern. For your case, you probably want a sortedset (or maybe a hash) where the keys are update times and the values are profile IDs, kept in sync (transactionally) with the `updatedAt` field in the profiles.